# How can I make difftool Meld insert spaces instead of tabs on editing?

Tags: 18.04, configuration, meld

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and apt-get installed [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) tool. Current version is 3.18.0.  I've got files to be compared with mixed tabs and spaces. I want them 1) to show up and 2) I want to insert 4 spaces instead of tabs when editing with meld. I find no relevant configuration setting. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In *Meld → Preferences → Editor*, set *Tab width*, enable *Insert spaces instead of tabs* and *Show whitespace*.
2. You also should disable all whitespace filters in *Text Filters*.